# Plot parametric mean in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas, scipy

I have a large real 1-d data set called r. I would like plot:

```
mean(log(1+a*r)) vs a, with a > -1 .
```

This is my code:

```
   rr=pd.read_csv('goog.csv')
   dd=rr['Close']
   series=pd.Series(dd)
   seriespct=series.pct_change()
   seriespct[0]=seriespct.mean()

   dum1 =[0]*len(dd)

   a=1.
   a_max = 1.
   a_step = 0.01

   a = scipy.arange(-3.+a_step, a_max, a_step)
   n = len(a)
   dum2 =[0]*n
   m=len(dd)

   for j in range(n):
      for i in range(m):
         dum1[i]=math.log(1+a[j]*seriespct[i])

   dum2[j]=scipy.mean(dum1)


   plt.plot(a,dum2)
   plt.show()
```

How can I do this in a more elgant way?

Comment: The mean is a single value. How do you plot it against a?

Comment: against different values of a.

Comment: But what have you tried already?

Comment: I am new of python. I have a code for doing it in R. Now I would like to learn python for statistical analysis, but I have no idea on how to do a thing like that.

Comment: After edits this should not be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend this:

```py
plt.plot(a, np.log(1 + r*a[:,None]).mean(1))
```

This has a big speed advantage because it avoids for-loops, and loops done in numpy are significantly faster in case your dataset is large.

```py
In [49]: a = np.arange(a_step-.3, a_max, a_step)

In [50]: r = np.random.random(100)

In [51]: timeit [scipy.mean(log(1+a[i]*r)) for i in range(len(a))]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.47 ms per loop

In [52]: timeit np.log(1 + r*a[:,None]).mean(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 384 µs per loop
```

It works by [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) so that `a` varies along one axis and `r` along another, then you can take the mean just along the axis that `r` varies along, so you still have an array that varies with `a` (and has the same shape as `a`):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = np.random.random(100)

a = 1.
a_max = 1.
a_step = 0.01
a = np.arange(a_step-.3, a_max, a_step)
a.shape
#(129,)
a = a[:,None] #adds a new axis, making this a column vector, same as: a = a.reshape(-1,1)
a.shape
#(129, 1)
(a*r).shape
#(129, 100)
loga = np.log(1 + a*r)
loga.shape
#(129,100)
mloga = loga.mean(axis=1) #take the mean along the 2nd axis where `a` varies
mloga.shape
#(129,)

plt.plot(a, mloga)
plt.show()
```

---

### ADDENDUM:

To avoid dependency on broadcasting, you can use `np.outer`:

```py
plt.plot(a, np.log(1 + np.outer(a,r)).mean(1))
```

Which has no need for reshaping `a` (skip the step `a = a[:,None]`)

Here's a simpler example, so you can see what's happening:

```py
r = np.exp(np.arange(1,5))
a = np.arange(5)

In [33]: r
Out[33]: array([  2.71828183,   7.3890561 ,  20.08553692,  54.59815003])

In [34]: a
Out[34]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [39]: r*a[:,None]
Out[39]: 
# this is  2.7...         7.3...        20.08...       54.5...         # times:
array([[   0.        ,    0.        ,    0.        ,    0.        ],   # 0
       [   2.71828183,    7.3890561 ,   20.08553692,   54.59815003],   # 1
       [   5.43656366,   14.7781122 ,   40.17107385,  109.19630007],   # 2
       [   8.15484549,   22.1671683 ,   60.25661077,  163.7944501 ],   # 3
       [  10.87312731,   29.5562244 ,   80.34214769,  218.39260013]])  # 4

In [40]: np.outer(a,r)
Out[40]: 
array([[   0.        ,    0.        ,    0.        ,    0.        ],
       [   2.71828183,    7.3890561 ,   20.08553692,   54.59815003],
       [   5.43656366,   14.7781122 ,   40.17107385,  109.19630007],
       [   8.15484549,   22.1671683 ,   60.25661077,  163.7944501 ],
       [  10.87312731,   29.5562244 ,   80.34214769,  218.39260013]])

# this is the mean of each column:
In [41]: (np.outer(a,r)).mean(1)
Out[41]: array([  0.        ,  21.19775622,  42.39551244,  63.59326866,  84.79102488])

# and the log of 1 + the above is:
In [42]: np.log(1+(np.outer(a,r)).mean(1))
Out[42]: array([ 0.        ,  3.09999121,  3.77035604,  4.16811021,  4.4519144 ])
```

Comment: (a*r).shape;   Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional. What's the problem?

Comment: Is `r` one dimensional (i.e., what is `r.shape`)?  And is `type(r)` a numpy array (`numpy.ndarray`)?  I know `a` is because you built it as `np.arange`.

Comment: rr=pd.read_csv('goog.csv'); dd=rr['Close'];series=pd.Series(dd);seriespct=series.pct_change()

Comment: Oh maybe pandas objects don't support broadcasting? I've never used pandas.  You could replace `r*a[:,None]` with `np.outer(a,r)`.  That is, don't reshape `a`, leave it regular 1d, and then use the outer function instead of regular multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scipy to do means.

You can use matplotlib to do plotting.

```
import scipy
from matplotlib import pyplot

#convert r from a python list to an 1-D array
r = scipy.array(r)

#edit these
a_max = 100
a_step = 0.1

a = scipy.arange(-1+a_step, a_max, a_step)
n = len(a)

pyplot.plot(a, [scipy.mean(log(1+a[i]*r)) for i in range(n)], 'b-')
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

Comment: I made an edit that might help (converted the list `r` into an array), but you're going to need to post more of your code.

Comment: If you have `nan`s in your data this will not produce the expected result.